# How buffer sql queries results

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

How console.log results of queries after all sql queries? I am using mysql connection. Now single push(results) is happening after main console.log(keys). I want buffer results of single queries and after that use it in another ways.

```
db.query(
    `INSERT INTO orders VALUES (?, ?, (SELECT SUM(currentPrice) FROM games WHERE games.id in (?)), 'pending', "?")`,
    [md5(Math.random() * 99999), email, ids, ids],
    async (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: "При выполнении заказа возникла ошибка" });
      }
      if (results) {
        const keys = [];

        await ids.forEach(async (id) => {
          await db.query(
            "SELECT * FROM gameworld.keys WHERE gameId = ? and used = 0 LIMIT 1",
            id,
            async (error, results) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log(error);
              }
              if (results) {
                console.log(results);
                await keys.push(results[0]);
                await db.query(
                  "UPDATE gameworld.keys SET used = 1 WHERE id = ?",
                  results[0].id
                );
              }
            }
          );
        });

        await db.query(
          "UPDATE order SET status = 'delivered' WHERE email = ?",
          email
        );

        await console.log(keys);
```

Comment: What 's the issue when you add the result var in a buffer, and then show the buffer in console? (I suppose you did). Is your problem waiting all the queries to finished?

Comment: yes. I just wanna wait results of all queries and then console.log buffer keys. But now last console.log doesn't wait results of sql queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this kind of structure:

```
async function main () {
    //do all your queries here with await
    var res = [];
    var [rows] = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM table');
    res.push(rows);

    //all queries are done
    console.log(res);
}
```